# Can I send a mail through gmail with swaks?

Tags: email, email-server, sendmail, gmail, mailbox

I have tried multiple ways to authenticate to gmail to send an email with [`swaks`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/swaks) without success.

**Is there a way to send a email through gmail with `swaks`**

Comment: 1) Could you provide error message generated by gmail in SMTP session? 2) Have you turned on authentication with less secure apps in google/gmail configuration?

Answer (score 2):

just for fun I tried and it works:

```
$ swaks -t user@domain.tld -s smtp.gmail.com:587 -tls -a LOGIN [enter]
Username: my.gmail.login
Password: my.password   [password will be visible here, no asteriks]
=== Trying smtp.gmail.com:587...
=== Connected to smtp.gmail.com.
<-  220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP a45sm2396859eda.3 - gsmtp
 -> EHLO e7250
<-  250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [77.249.1.91]
<-  250-SIZE 35882577
<-  250-8BITMIME
<-  250-STARTTLS
<-  250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
<-  250-PIPELINING
<-  250-CHUNKING
<-  250 SMTPUTF8
 -> STARTTLS
<-  220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
=== TLS started with cipher TLSv1.2:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:128
=== TLS no local certificate set
=== TLS peer DN="/C=US/ST=California/L=Mountain View/O=Google Inc/CN=smtp.gmail.com"
 ~> EHLO e7250
<~  250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [77.249.1.91]
<~  250-SIZE 35882577
<~  250-8BITMIME
<~  250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH
<~  250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
<~  250-PIPELINING
<~  250-CHUNKING
<~  250 SMTPUTF8
 ~> AUTH LOGIN
<~  334 xxxxxxxxxxx
 ~> xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
<~  334 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
 ~> xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx==
<~  235 2.7.0 Accepted
 ~> MAIL FROM:<user@host>
<~  250 2.1.0 OK a45sm2396859eda.3 - gsmtp
 ~> RCPT TO:<user@domain.tld>
<~  250 2.1.5 OK a45sm2396859eda.3 - gsmtp
 ~> DATA
<~  354  Go ahead a45sm2396859eda.3 - gsmtp
 ~> Date: Sun, 23 Apr 2017 10:35:17 +0200
 ~> To: user@domain.tld
 ~> From: user@host
 ~> Subject: test Sun, 23 Apr 2017 10:35:17 +0200
 ~> X-Mailer: swaks v20130209.0 jetmore.org/john/code/swaks/
 ~> 
 ~> This is a test mailing
 ~> 
 ~> .
<~  250 2.0.0 OK 1492936526 a45sm2396859eda.3 - gsmtp
 ~> QUIT
<~  221 2.0.0 closing connection a45sm2396859eda.3 - gsmtp
=== Connection closed with remote host.
```

Obviously you need to make sure the usual stuff is possible: firewall allows to connect using smtp to gmail, login/password are correct, etc. One additional layer of security is to create an 'app' password for your gmail account (https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en) . Your can then be sure that only this app will be using this app password, so if compromised just revoke the app password.

Answer (score 2):

You have to change security settings of your accoutn.

By running

```
 swaks -tls -t  -s smtp.gmail.com:587 -tls -a LOGIN [enter]
```

You recieve a mail like

[image]

with a link to a page with a button allowing to use the app:

[image]